# Sms Application Android develop

Tags: android, sms

I need to develop an android application which when receive a message reply automatically
to the sender of the message(without pressing any button) with a predefined text like(thank you for contacting we will contact you soon).
Any links,suggestions most welcome.
If anybody explain in brief what should i do then it will help me a lot.
I already read visit http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android link. It help me but eclipse say The type SmsManager is deprecated. so what another type should be use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. First listen for incoming sms.
2. Send sms.

Parts 1 and 2 are well tested with Android 2.3.

Answer (score 2):

That's true that SmsManager in android.telephony.gsm package was deprecated. This class has been replaced by SmsManager class from android.telephony package. I resolve this problem by change imported package android.telephony.gsm to android.telephony for SmsManager class.
You can read the documentation. [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html) is SmsManager documentation from android.telephony.gsm package and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) is SmsManager documentation from android.telephony package.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `android.telephony.SmsManager` is depreciated . You should use `android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager` to send SMS and to send SMS automatically you have to use **BroadcaseReceiver** for incoming SMS.

Comment: You mean to say i should write a class which extends BroadcastReceiver.